# GWT MVP Storing session data

Tags: google-app-engine, session, gwt

I'm having a mvp application and I need to temp save some `height` data from a ResizeablePanel (within the panel is a `DockPanel` which needs to be init with a certain height in `px`). Now I'm not sure whats the best way to do this. webcontext, eventbus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in your View or in your Activity/Presenter. You can even store it in your entry point class. There is no single correct answer here - it all depends on your requirements and patterns that you use.

There is no need to get EventBus or sessions involved.